# how to create dependencies in dependencies [postgresql]

Tags: postgresql, dependencies

I currently have a problem on the architecture of my database.

I have this layout

```
   account
      |
    likes
      |
    matche
```

"i cannot have a match without like and i cannot have likes without account"

So my account table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
login varchar(17) NOT NULL,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
password varchar(60) NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
create_at varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'))
```

my likes table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS likes(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
liked_by_id_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES account ON DELETE CASCADE, 
id_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES account ON DELETE CASCADE,
create_at varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'))
```

my matche table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matche(
id SERIAL, id_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES account ON DELETE CASCADE,
id_other_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES account ON DELETE CASCADE,
id_like_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES likes ON DELETE CASCADE,
id_like_other_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES likes ON DELETE CASCADE,
create_at varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'))")
```

"i cannot have a match without like and i cannot have likes without account"

If an account is destroyed, all his likes are destroyed and all matches created by the likes are destroyed. If the like or the account which it is linked are destroyed, matche his also destroyed.

So my problem is, how create perfect dependancies between my tables for they suppress in chain.

I read the postgresql documentation and searched all the way to , I don't find the way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. One more question: Please describe what 'perfect dependency' would look like in this case. Are you satisfied with that cascaded-delete-behavior so far? Do you also want cascaded updates? Do you want to restrict something? Please go into details. Cheers.

Comment: no updates and no restrict just delete. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the last two signs `")` from the last create statement. Creating the tables will work then. But you'll get dependencies looking like this:

```
  account
  |      \
  likes  |
  |      /
  matche
```

That's because you referenced the `account` table twice in the `matche` table.
Still all likes and matche(s) will be deleted if you delete a user and all matche(s) will be deleted on deleting a like-record.

Just guessing - for not knowing what you're after - you could do without the columns `matche.id_user` and `matche.id_other_user`.

Think about adding a constraint both to `likes` and `matches` to prevent having the same account id and the same likes id twice in one row.

The `matche` table has no primary key at present.

Comment: yes sorry it's looking like you say. Actually with my scheme i have this error with golang : "pq: insert or update on table "matche" violates foreign key constraint "matche_id_user_fkey". But i have no foreign key

Comment: This is because the line `id_user int NOT NULL REFERENCES account ON DELETE CASCADE` creates a foreign key constraint `matche_id_user_fkey`. Look in the table definition (it's `\d+ matche` in psql or just brows your pgAdmin or other sql tool) and you'll find it. You try to insert values that are not present in `account.id`. At this point you either should check the insert statement or think about getting rid of the columns `matche.id_user` and `matche.id_other_user`. I'm pretty sure you don't need them as you can retrieve these data via join from `account` whenever needed.